# Как посмотреть свободную память из терминала в Linux?

Tags: linux

Как посмотреть свободную память из терминала в Linux ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

С помощью команды free.

```
alpha@beta:~$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           994        683        310          0         59        377
-/+ buffers/cache:        247        747
Swap:         1027          0       1027
```

Answer (score 3):

vmstat -s

```
  8028960  total memory
  7781948  used memory
   651644  active memory
  6895416  inactive memory
   247012  free memory
   221644  buffer memory
  7118196  swap cache
  2064376  total swap
    46192  used swap
  2018184  free swap
 50023867 non-nice user cpu ticks
   866103 nice user cpu ticks
 42902813 system cpu ticks
3551084559 idle cpu ticks
  3991557 IO-wait cpu ticks
     5359 IRQ cpu ticks
  1682224 softirq cpu ticks
   666653 stolen cpu ticks
3275206999 pages paged in
686649844 pages paged out
     8000 pages swapped in
    11698 pages swapped out
4074027452 interrupts
2221948876 CPU context switches
1418184416 boot time
 76530955 forks
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно ещё так:

```
[hop@hey.la-la.ley ~]$ cat /proc/meminfo 
MemTotal:        3145728 kB
MemFree:         2328424 kB
Cached:           631824 kB
Buffers:               0 kB
Active:           413668 kB
Inactive:         349776 kB
Active(anon):       7960 kB
Inactive(anon):   127060 kB
Active(file):     405708 kB
Inactive(file):   222716 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:        524288 kB
SwapFree:         511988 kB
Dirty:              4356 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        135020 kB
Shmem:              3400 kB
Slab:              53780 kB
SReclaimable:      39160 kB
SUnreclaim:        14620 kB
```